# How to pass variable(which stores string) from one page to next while using dynamic link?

Tags: php, get, dynamic-links

On my first page I have created dynamic link this way:

```
do
{
   $FilterModule = $row_mysql['Module']; /* Say it's value is 'xyz' for particular case */
   echo "<a href='filterquery.php?filter=$FilterModule'>$FilterModule</a>";
} while($row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult));
```

Now when i click on above link from the first page, it takes me to a second page with url: `filterquery.php?filter=xyz`. On this page I am using `$FilterModule = $_GET['FilterModule'];` to get the value(`='xyz'`). But I get an error:

> 'Undefined index: FilterModule'.

Not sure what mistake i am making? Please help..

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `$_GET['filter'];` because thats what you called the parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$_GET['filter']` rather than `$_GET['FilterModule']` because that's the name of the parameter you're assigning a value to in the URL.

When you access the `GET` array, it uses the variables passed in the URL, so

`filterquery.php?filter=xyz&filter2=abc`

would produce the following key-value pairs in the `_GET` array:

```
$_GET = array(
   [filter]  = 'xyz',
   [filter2] = 'abc'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value with `$_GET['filter']` which is the parameter given in `filterquery.php?filter=xyz`